# (Android) How can I find all ImageViews in my xml file?

Tags: xml, android-imageview

I would like to add each image view to an Array List, regardless of how many there are in the UI (so it can be changed without having change in code). Is there a way to do this? Something like a `findAllViews(ImageView)` method would be perfect.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Please elaborate what you need to do...some code or any of your tries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over all the views in your xml using:

```
RelativeLayout yourLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

 for (int i = 0; i < yourLayout .getChildCount(); i++) {

        View subView = yourLayout .getChildAt(i);

        if (subView instanceof ImageView) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) subView;
          //manipulate the imageView
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
int childsNumber = relativeLayout.getChildCount();
```

where relativeLayout is the layout that contains all your ImageViews only. If you have other views with you relativeLayout, you can count these other views and subtract them. Here is an example:

If you have for example various ImageViews with 2 TextViews and 1 Button, you will do the following:

```
int childsNumber = relativeLayout.getChildCount() - 3;
```

where 3 is the total views that are not ImageView.

Of course you can use any other kind of layout rather than RelativeLayout, just follow the logic I wrote. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted a way to do this without hardcoding anything (like the number of other views). Udi I's idea to use instanceof is a good way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering all ImageViews under **Root**

```
 /**
 * View is the root view
 * i.e in case of activity just pass R.id.content
 * or in case of Fragment pass it the reference you get from LayoutInflator
 */

 List<View> listOfImgViews = new ArrayList<>();

 private void viewIterator(View view){

            if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)){

                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++){

                    if(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageView){
                        listOfImgViews.add(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));

                    }else if( ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup && !(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i) instanceof AdapterView)){
                        viewIterator(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                    }


                }

            }
        }
```